# connecting to vpn on server and connect to that server and use the vpn on there

Tags: networking, vpn, samba, shared-folders, ubuntu-server

This might sound a bit weird, but I'm asking if it's possible to connect my ubuntu server to a VPN and then connect with other devices to this server in some way so I can access the shared folders made accessible by the VPN.

**Why** I want to do such strange thing is that the VPN configuration is quite complicated and has a changing password.

Because I got multiple devices with different kinds of OS, I thought of something to simplyfiy stuff in my home network, so that only the ubuntu server holds the configuration and all the other devices can use the shared folders with a simpler configuration.

So security is almost secondary, because all the devices which are going to connect to that server are known and should be able to do so with a simple user/pass-combination maybe.

Comment: The other devices would have to be connected to the VPN in order for idea to work.

Comment: so i cant just share the shares from the vpn over samba with the other devices?

Comment: (this idea came quite late to me..)

Comment: You would still need to connect the devices to the same VPN the server is connected to.  That is the general idea of a VPN, you create a virtual private network, that is seperate from the network you are already connected to.

Comment: but wouldnt the shares appear as folders on the server connected to the vpn?
these folders i could share via samba, so its a simple smb for the devices?